# Display image with image URL from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

I really don't know what I'm doing here. I can display the url from the database but I can't figure out how to add the html code

```
$sql = "SELECT IMG_URL, Birthdate, FirstName, LastName FROM Student";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "IMG: " . $row["IMG_URL"]. " Birthdate: " . $row["Birthdate"]. " - Name: " . $row["FirstName"]. " " . $row["LastName"]. "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: so you do know php, but you don't know html? strange combination. what could you not get to work? writing an <img src=""> shouldnt be that hard.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from doing it in the HTML. You could do it in the SQL though if you wanted. `SELECT concat('<img src="', IMG_URL, '" />'), Birthdate, FirstName, LastName FROM Student`; assuming `IMG_URL` is only the URL and wasn't user provided data (if user provided data could open you to XSS injection).

Comment: Stop working and go to sleep, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're not outputting any HTML at all from this code.  Insert an `<img>` tag around the outputted image:

```
    echo "IMG: <img src=\"" . $row["IMG_URL"]. "\" /> Birthdate: " . $row["Birthdate"]. " - Name: " . $row["FirstName"]. " " . $row["LastName"]. "<br>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!